# How to use layout-land and android:configChanges=orientation|screenSize together in application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

My application requires layout-land when changed the orientation of device.
I use dialog for input the name but when orientation changed, then dialog is disappear.

So that is use the **android:configChanges=orientation|screenSize** in manifest file.

Now the problem is that android:configChanges attribute is not working with layout-land because it prevents from restart an activity.

My application requires both **layout-land and android:configChanges=orientation|screenSize working together.**

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Dialog Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `android:configChanges=orientation|screenSize` to solve the problem with a dialog that doesn't reappear on rotation. Make sure you use a [`DialogFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html) instead of a simple `AlertDialog`, a `DialogFragment` should reappear automatically when the device is rotated.

Comment: I use `Dialog` for creating an Custom dialog in application.
Can i make Custom DialogFragment in activity and Fragment both? @Egor

Comment: Just override onCreateDialog() inside the DialogFragment and return your custom dialog implementation

Comment: Which package should i have to import for DialogFragment `android.support.v4.app` or `android.app` ? @Egor

Comment: I'd recommend using the one from the Support library.

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. Please don't forget to accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are handling config changes with `android:configChanges=orientation|screenSize` Android will not restart the app. SO that laout-land will not apply.For this you have to override the method

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

This callback will be invoked once orientation changed, then inflate the layout-land layout xml and add update the content view of custom dialog.

Comment: I don't any answers other than this one!